# Mozilla Firefox Developer tools - what are the grayed out selectors?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

In the Firefox developer tools rules view the selectors are pink. Sometimes there grayed out selectors together with the pink ones. What do they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a rule has multiple selectors, the ones that apply to the selected element are brighter (for me, green; but apparently for you, pink) and the ones that do not apply to the selected element are dimmed.

Answer (score 11):

In my experience, the greyed out html elements are those with display: none;